# Save .dta files with long strings in R

Tags: r, string, stata

I have to save an R-dataset in Stata's .dta format.
    The dataset contains, among other data, a single column containing long strings (column 3).

test data:

```
r_data <- data.frame( ae= 1, be= 2, ce= "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
                       ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

export to dta

```
library(foreign)
write.dta(r_data, file = "r_data.dta")
```

results in this warning message:
Warning message:

```
In write.dta(r_data, file = "r_data.dta") :
  character strings of >244 bytes in column 3 will be truncated
```

Furthermore, I can't open the file in Stata (14 SE) at all due to an error stating:

```
. use "r_data.dta" 
file not Stata format
    .dta file contains 1 invalid storage-type code.  
File uses invalid codes other than code 0.
    r(610);
```

How can I save longer strings as a .dta file?
R-solution prefered because I am not experienced with Stata.

PS: The indirect route via a CSV-file does not work, because the resulting CSV-file is too big for my little RAM when importing in Stata.

Comment: You want to use the `readstata13` package, which allows you to write stata 14 files. I haven't investigated the long strings issue though.

Comment: perfect hint. library(readstata13)
save.dta13(r_data,file ="r_data.dta") solves the problem. I'd accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but deserves to be closed:

Use the `haven` package to write to a dta-file in Stata 14 format.

```
library(haven)

r_data <- data.frame(ae = 1, be = 2, ce = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

write_dta(r_data, "r_data.dta")
```